# Iterating in Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('div', 'thread')
  for i in soup:
    print i
```

I'll take only this part of the code because that's where I'm getting stuck in.

Soup returns a list, I tried to use ' '.join() to have a literal string and it didn't work, because it's expected a string, not a tag. I guess it's sort of bug.

Iterating, it prints on screen all the list without comma.

But what I want is to get a href content inside div cass="thread"

I tried many things like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('div', 'thread')
  for i in soup:
    print BeautifulSoup(i)('a')['href']
```

The last code gives me 'NoneType' object is not callabe.

I'm trying a lot of combinations but I am indeed stuck in, I can't have it working at all. I don't know what to do after many failed try-outs. It's frustrating.

Comment: Replace the parentheses around 'a' with square brackets. Does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like

```
divs = BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('div','thread')  
for div in divs:  
    print div.find('a').attr['href'] # may it be map(a.attrs)['href'], I don't remember now
```

Answer (score 1):

taking a look at the documentation for this module/class (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) - the second argument for `findAll` is a json object, not a string.  have you tried this instead:

```
BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('div', { 'class': 'thread' })
```